# Expected primary expression before const. Narrowed it down but still can't find it.

Tags: c++, vi

I'm getting a "Expected primary expression before const" and spent a while trying to locate the problem but can't seem to find it...I narrowed it down to the .h file and the constructors. Here's the code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#ifndef VEHICLE_H
#define VEHICLE_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle{
        protected:
                char *name;
                static ostream *out;
        public:
                Vehicle();
                Vehicle(string n);
                Vehicle (const Vehicle & b);
                ~Vehicle();
                Vehicle& operater =(const Vehicle &b);
                virtual void print() = 0;
                virtual void read() = 0;

};

#endif // VEHICLE_H
~
```

The constructors in a separate file.

```
#include "vehicle.h"

Vehicle :: Vehicle(){

        name = "";

}

Vehicle :: Vehicle(string n){

        name = n.c_str();
}

Vehicle :: Vehicle(const Vehicle & a){

        int len = strlen(a.name)+ 1;

        name = new char[len];
        strcpy(name,a.name);

}
Vehicle :: Vehicle &operater = (const Vehicle &b){

        if(this = &b){

                return *this;

        }

        int len = strlen(a.name)+ 1;
        name = new char[len];
        strcpy(name,a.name);

        return *this;
}

Vehicle:: ~Vehicle(){

        delete [] name;

}
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Line? Full error message?

Comment: You have a typo `Vehicle& operater =(const Vehicle &b);` --> `Vehicle& operator =(const Vehicle &b);`

Comment: You could have narrowed it down even further by just removing lines or functions, one by one, until it compiles.

Comment: Wow...that was incredibly stupid.....Thanks guys. Time to go learn more spelling. The error message was on the line with the operator so that's why I didn't remove the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class vehicle you spelled operator wrong:

```
Vehicle& operater =(const Vehicle &b);
```

edit: you spell it wrong every time.

Comment: Thanks...that was the dumbest mistake that took so long. Thanks for your time.